# How can I fix the vertical alignment of my horizontal menu?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, alignment

I'm having a problem with the vertical alignment; it aligns to the top when I want it to be at the bottom:

[image]

My **HTML** code is:

```
<div id="hor_menu">
<img src="header.jpg" border="0" style="float:left" width="200px" height="80px"/>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.alistapart.com/d/slidingdoors/v1/v1.html#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="http://www.alistapart.com/d/slidingdoors/v1/v1.html#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.alistapart.com/d/slidingdoors/v1/v1.html#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.alistapart.com/d/slidingdoors/v1/v1.html#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.alistapart.com/d/slidingdoors/v1/v1.html#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My **CSS** code is:

```
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  }
#hor_menu *{
  margin:0;padding:0
  }
#hor_menu {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  background: #000 url('bg.jpg') repeat-x bottom;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:15px;
  }
#hor_menu ul {
  list-style:none;
  }  
#hor_menu li {
  float:left;
  }  
#hor_menu a {
  display:block;
  padding:5px 13px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  }
#hor_menu a:hover {
  background: #000 url('bg_hover.jpg') repeat-x bottom;
  }
#hor_menu .current a{
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -khtml-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    -khtml-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff url('bg_current.jpg') repeat-x top;
  color:#000;
  }
```

NOTE: the code above DOES NOT have any attempt to align to the bottom.

Comment: I can't see what the problem is: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/XYrWZ/

Comment: the problem Start when I put more "height" to the "#hor_menu"

Comment: Please do not delete questions that receive helpful answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to fix this is to use `display:inline-block; vertical-align:bottom`.

```
#hor_menu ul, #hor_menu img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: inline-block;
    /* if you need ie6/7 support */
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/XYrWZ/3/

Comment: the thing is that I want to put a Logo to the left of 200 x 80 and when I do that, the <li>s don't align to the bottom (I will update the code up)

Comment: no, sorry I thought you used my code... I will try it in a sec

Comment: Well, it works in the jsFiddle demo. What browser are you using? I hope you don't say IE6.

Comment: I tried with Google Chrome, Opera, Fire Fox (all updated few weeks ago)

Comment: ..you have to remove `style="float:left"` from the `img`.